# php passing a variable to another page

Tags: php, mysql, json, variables

any help will be appreciated.

I have 2 pages
1. products.php
2. product_mysql.php
I want to pass a variable from products.php to product_mysql.php and return the results on products.php

I'm getting the correct result on "product_mysql.php?partNo=12807" but I need to on products.php?partNo=12807.

if I hard code the partNo to "12807" in the SELECT query, it returns the correct result on products.php.

product_mysql.php

```
    <?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");


$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "prod_db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
}

$partNoid = $_GET['partNo'];
$result = $conn->query("SELECT partNo, productName, unitPrice FROM       tblProducts WHERE partNo=$partNoid");


$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"PartNo":"'  . $rs["partNo"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"productName":"'   . $rs["productName"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"unitPrice":"'. $rs["unitPrice"] . '"}'; 
}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

products.php

```
<h1>Customers</h1>
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "product_mysql.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" +
        arr[i].PartNo +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].productName +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].unitPrice +
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope this isn't a production site. You're leaving your database **wide open** to SQL Injection.

Comment: Hi Darren, no its not production, being a newbie any help with securing would be helpful.  What can I do to resolve?

FYI. this code is straight out of w3schools site, so that is disappointing.

Comment: You'd be best to read up on `PDO` or Mysqli Prepared Statements. Also, avoid w3schools, read [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com)

Answer (score 0):

This may because of the type of `$_GET['partNo']` is not matching to int, so you'll need to add a intval() function around it (meaning parsing the value to `int` explicitly:

```
$partNoid = intval($_GET['partNo']);
```

Not only it protects from non-numeric values passing in, but also it keeps integrity in your program.

And you might want to check if `$_GET['partNo']` first, connect and fetch from database later.

Hope it helps you ;)